# Exclude "sourceAsString" from SearchResponse

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am calling ElasticSearch Java API for search. In response, it returns me `sourceAsString`. My application does not need field. `sourceAsMap` is being used in the application.

Is there any way to exclude `sourceAsString` from search response using ElasticSearch Java API?
I am using Rest High level client version 6.4.

My sample call:

```
//SearchRequest is prepared in different class.
public SearchResponse performSearch(SearchRequest searchRequest) {
    try {
        return highLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```